# Standard error of a proportion on a 2 x 2 contingency table

Tags: variance, standard-error, proportion, contingency-tables

Why on a 2 x 2 table such as

[image]

where $p = \frac{a}{a+b}$

the standard error of $p$ is

$$\left(\frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{(a+b+c+d)^2(a+b)
}\right)^{1/2}$$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the null hypothesis of no difference, the common rate estimator is $p_c=(a+c)/N$, where $N=a+b+c+d$. For $p=\frac a {a+b}$, the variance estimate is $\frac {p_c(1-p_c)}{a+b}= \frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{(a+b+c+d)^2(a+b)}$ because $Var(\frac XN) = \frac{\pi (1-\pi)}N $for binomial distribution $X\sim B(n,\pi)$. The square root of the estimated variance is called standard error.

Comment: The 'common rate estimator' is the "probability of Success" in the binomial with the column $a+c$ being the Success column? And $p=\frac{a}{a+b}$ is the probability of Success among the first row, for example, corresponding to subjects treated with a specific drug?

Comment: Yes to both questions.